# Fixing Quotes After Migration To WordPress

Tags: wordpress, escaping

I migrated our site to WordPress from a custom blog format that we wrote ourselves. As a result, the database entries contained a lot of escaped characters and other such issues. In moving these over, WordPress handles a lot of the escaping in a much better way, but our old articles will always have those characters.

Here is an example: http://zombiesquirrel.com/?p=117

Notice that there are parts with strange characters, like so: `John Carterâ€™s`.

My question is: is there any possible way to fix this without manually going to each article and changing the characters?

Answer (score 1):

I would say this has something to do with character encoding. If you are transferring from one database to the next I would check and see if both the character encoding of both databases match. WordPress goes into detail about this and might shed some light on your problem.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets

Comment: Some of the characters you see are the result of Microsoft Word "smart quotes" or whatever. The others, like escaping slashes, are the result of the escaping method we used for securing our database content on the old site. So some of them were put there intentionally by us, and this is something I'd like to perform some sort of quick find and replace on without going through each individual post.